# Is there a way to programmatically mute the sound on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

Is there a way to programmatically mute the sound on OSX without using private APIs and in a way that is accepted by the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2):

**FOR MAC OS X:** [This tutorial](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SoundVolume) might be of assistance.

**FOR IOS:** No.

Sound Mute is a system-wide setting. So for applications developed using the official SDK cannot change (and in most cases cannot even access) system-wide settings.

It is technically possible to change the system volume through the private `AVSystemController` class in `Celestial.framework`, but will prevent your app from getting Apple's approval.

Comment: The tutorial link is dead

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, see Srikar's answer. I believe he's got it covered.

On iOS, `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer].volume = 0.0` will mute the audio output. If there is an `MPVolumeView` present in your view hierarchy, it will do this without visual feedback; if there is not, it may present the volume change popup you see when you press the hardware volume buttons on the device.

Comment: The question is about Mac OS, the iOS answer is irrelevant to the OP.

Comment: I know. I was being comprehensive.