# how do I turn the sound off in objective-c / cocoa for the entire mac for 30 seconds when F10 is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to write a simple cocoa program that mutes the mac's sound for 30 seconds when F10 is pressed.  Can you point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Which part of this task are you having trouble with?

Comment: Not a good question.  Show what research you've already done.  On the basis of that research, propose a direction and have people validate whether that direction is correct or not.

Comment: I'm an okay iphone objective-c cocoa programmer.  Why is this not a good question?  I'm just asking the stackoverflow community to point me to the right direction on how to find the right library to build a simple native OSX app that does this.  I've done zero research so far.  I thought I'd start here.  Is that not okay?

Comment: In general, SO encourages you to do your research first and then ask the community for clarification or validation, not just say "show me an answer."

Comment: thanks wadesworld, I get what you are saying.  I looked at your blog.  You are obviously a knowledgable engineer.  I didn't mean to break the rules.  I think the answer http://stackoverflow.com/users/446458/jeremy gave me below was perfect.  It would have taken me hours to get to the place he got me in 5 mins.  I guess I'm thinking more like IRC chat room and that's just not what some people want SO to become.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A poster had a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431412/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-mute-the-sound-on-osx).  One of the answers includes a [link to a tutorial](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SoundVolume) for tweaking the sound which may be of use.

Comment: thanks!  ended up making just the app I wanted.  I have an icon on my desktop now.  Every time a comercial comes on Spotify I launch it, and my sound is muted for 25 seconds, then the program turns the sound back on and exits.